# Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.3:build Exception caught: HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:2375

Tags: docker, spring-boot, maven-3, spring-cloud

Deploy `Spring Cloud` project with `docker`, some code in the `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- tag::plugin[] -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                    <dockerDirectory>${project.basedir}</dockerDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- end::plugin[] -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

when i run the command: `mvn package docker:build`, it throws errors:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.3:build (default) on project users-microservice: Exception caught: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.spotify.docker.client.shaded.javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:2375 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
```

why will it connect to localhost:2375? Any idea, i will appreciate!

Comment: Is there anything running on `localhost:2375`. `localhost` inside a container's local interface refers to the container if you wish to connect to `:2375` on the conatiner's host you need to use host IP instead.

Comment: @stacksonstacks, inside the docker, i don't assign any service to the port:2375

Answer (score 4):

Please update your `docker-maven-plugin`'s version from 0.4.3 to 1.0.0

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- tag::plugin[] -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                    <dockerDirectory>${project.basedir}</dockerDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- end::plugin[] -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: @HerilMuratovic That's great!